# Encrypting message in Javascript and decrypting in Python (FastAPI, CryptoJS, AES)

Tags: javascript, python, aes, cryptojs

I am currently trying to encrypt a message in Javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

var message = 'Message';
var key = '1234567812345678';
var encryptedAES = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB});
var url2 = new URL('http://localhost:8000/decrypt/');
$("#encrypt").on("click", evt => {
  fetch(url2, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: encryptedAES
  }).then().catch((error) => { console.log(error.message); });
});
```

And then have it sent over to FastAPI in Python via a POST request:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/decrypt/')
async def decrypt(request: Request):
    key = '1234567812345678'
    data = await request.body()
    new_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_ECB)
    final = unpad(cipher.decrypt(new_data), 16)
    return final
```

It seems that the encrypted message is sent over successfully, however I get this error on the Python side:

```
File "C:\Users\realt\OneDrive\Desktop\Senior Design I\LoyaltyAPI\LoyaltyAPI\.\main.py", line 52, in decrypt
    final = unpad(cipher.decrypt(new_data), 16)
  File "C:\Users\realt\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\Crypto\Util\Padding.py", line 92, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

Anyone have any ideas as to how I should go about properly padding? I'm just unsure as to how to apply that to the Javascript end. If my Javascript end is fine, how else can I go about fixing this? Any feedback is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: In the current code, the keys in both codes differ. Regarding CryptoJS, the format of the key material determines how it is processed. You can find more details in the CryptoJS documentation (The Cipher Input) and many CryptoJS posts on SO.